# how to call chrome extension(Full Page Screen Capture) or 360browser’s screenshot

Tags: javascript, screenshot

I want to save full web page as a image or a pdf.

- I tried to use `html2canvas` but it doesn't support `iframe` element.
- I tried to use `phantomjs` but it doesn't work in Windows Server 2003 Operation System.

I usually use 360 browsers' plugin and Google Chrome's Full Page Screen Capture.

How can I call the Chrome plugins using JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: java is not javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Full Page Screen Capture**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) extension.

Regarding calling this extension by javascript:
As far as I know the **`externally_connectable`** is the only official way to call an extension or send messages (maybe with data) from a web page (using javascript) as mentioned [**here**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

If extension not support being **`externally_connectable`**, this requires editing the extension and add predefined values for every single domain you wish to integrate with.

If this is the case we can play with a workaround to integrate with any website (and not to define any domains)

If you just want to notify the other side (extension) about some thing, you can use the native **`JS Event`** dispatching it on the document from one side(web page) and listening to it at document also from the other side(extension) as the document is shared between the extension content script pages and the web page.

You can't use **`JS CustomEvent`** to send data as every time you send data, you receive it empty as a result of **`sandbox effect`** of any extension.

If you want to share data (may be the limit of scrolling when taking the screenshot) so the only workaround I know so far is to have a combination between some sort of a storage and the **`JS native Event`** mechanism.

The solution in steps (suppose you need the web page to call and send some data to the extension):

1. Make an event on **`document`** from the web page.
2. Save the data temporarily inside any storage technology you prefer
   (localStorage, the DOM itself, or what ever..)
3. Edit the extension and add event listener to receive the event at the other side (extension) by listening on the document.
4. Read data and remove it.